# FPDF with Classic ASP, Image Error

Tags: asp-classic, fpdf

Let's preface this post by saying... Yes, I know I'm a dinosaur for using Classic ASP in this day and age!

I'm using FPDF.asp to generate a PDF on the fly.

Everything works fine and as expected on my test server.  On my live server, however, I encounter an error, if I try to output an image as part of my PDF.  I know the syntax is correct, since it works on the test server as it should.

The error I receive on my live server is: "File does not begin with '%PDF-'."

If I comment out the line that adds the image, the file loads up properly and error-free!

Does anyone have any idea, as to what may need to be corrected on the live server to eliminate this problem???

Any help would be most appreciated.

Mitch

Comment: What webserver are you using on your localhost and what is the live server running?

Comment: Good question!  The localhost is IIS 5.1.  The live server is also IIS, but I'm not sure what version.

Comment: What you need to do on the live server is add `pdf` to the Mime Types. Here's a how-to for IIS7 -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx

Comment: To discover what version of IIS the live server is running, save this to an ASP file -- `<%=Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_SOFTWARE")) %>` -- and browse to it.

Comment: @stealthyninja: thanks for the advise so far!  So, I checked the server and it is IIS 5.0,  I'll check to make sure the pdf Mime Type is there.  One thing that puzzles me that the PDF is generated without a problem on the live server when there is no image in the PDF.  Wouldn't that mean the pdf Mime Type is probably already added?

Answer (score 1):

Update!

Not sure why having an image or not makes the difference, BUT the solution turned out to be that I had some HTML code mixed in with the output and this caused FPDF to fail when an image was included.

Removed the HTML code and problem solved!

-Mitch